# WFS link not displaying QGIS

Tags: qgis, wfs

I have this WFS link: https://data.aadnc-aandc.gc.ca/geomatics/services/Donnees_Ouvertes-Open_Data/Claim_minier_NU_Mineral_Claim/MapServer/WFSServer

And I can't get it to display in QGIS, I've tried changing symbology and different projections but no luck. The source is this website: https://data.sac-isc.gc.ca/geomatics/services/Donnees_Ouvertes-Open_Data/Claim_minier_NU_Mineral_Claim/MapServer/WFSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WFS

Can anyone else get it to display?

Comment: Works OK for me in both QGIS 3.22.16 and AutoCAD Map 3D 2024, although you need to "Invert axis orientation". Are you giving it enough time? How long? In case it was temporarily down, did you try again?

Comment: You should use `urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4617`  as it is the only supported CRS.  according to the GetCapabilities response, otherwise you'll be doing reprojection on the fly which may slow the rendering of the 33394 features ~ https://data.sac-isc.gc.ca/geomatics/services/Donnees_Ouvertes-Open_Data/Claim_minier_NU_Mineral_Claim/MapServer/WFSServer?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&typenames=Donnees_Ouvertes-Open_Data_Claim_minier_NU_Mineral_Claim:Claim_minier_NU_Mineral_Claim&version=2.0.0&resulttype=hits

Answer (score 1):

It works for me, though it takes a long time (and 76 requests) to download all of it.

[image]